# TinyMCE Angular 8 Instance

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an issue on the tinymce angular 8 SPA
How do you remove the instance of the component or
How do i force to reInitialize the TinyMCE

Thank you,

Pong

Comment: Please provide a demo code to replicate the issue. you can use stackblitz.com to do so. Otherwirse, the question will be closed soon

Answer (score 0):

Just put the editor into *ngIf structural directive, and the component will be removed by your condition